# Why do we need to discard one dummy variable?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, categorical-data

I have learned that, for creating a regression model, we have to take care of categorical variables by converting them into dummy variables. As an example, if, in our data set, there is a variable like location:

```
Location 
----------
Californian
NY
Florida
```

We have to convert them like:

```
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

However, it was suggested that we have to discard one dummy variable, no matter how many dummy variables are there.

Why do we need to discard one dummy variable?

Comment: Because the third dummy can be explained as the linear combination of the first two: FL = 1 - (CA + NY).

Comment: @chainD but what is the explanation for more than three dummy variable ?

Comment: Whatever the total, it will just be 1 less than the total number of categories that you have. Extending your example, say all 50 states were represented in the dataset. For a given individual, say you look at the first 49 dummies which happen to be all zeros, then you know that the last dummy is a 1 even without looking (assuming everyone in the dataset is from one of the 50 states). In other words, the information of the last dummy is already contained in the result of the first 49, so to speak.

Comment: if it is not spring, not summer and not autumn then it is winter!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply put because one level of your categorical feature (here location) become the reference group during dummy encoding for regression and is redundant. I am quoting form [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/contrasts.html) "A categorical variable of K categories, or levels, usually enters a regression as a sequence of K-1 dummy variables. This amounts to a linear hypothesis on the level means."

This is already discussed at this very nice [stats.stackexchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115049/why-do-we-need-to-dummy-code-categorical-variables).

I was told there is an advanced course by Yandex in Coursera that covers this subject in more details if you still have doubts, see [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science). Note you can always audit the course content for free. ;-)

Another nice post if you want a thorough explanation with lots of examples with statistical perspective and not being limited to only dummy coding, see [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/) from UCLA (in R)

Note that if you using `pandas.get_dummies`, there is a parameter i.e. `drop_first` so that whether to get k-1 dummies out of k categorical levels by removing the first level. Please note `default = False`, meaning that the reference is not dropped and k dummies created out of k categorical levels!

Comment: Notice that this is only true if your model has an intercept (i.e., a constant term).

Otherwise, by using one-hot-encoding and not discarding one dummy variable, you are implicitly adding an intercept.

Comment: See this discussion for a follow up question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/84061/71442

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need to* drop a level, depending on your use case.

See
[In which cases shouldn't we drop the first level of categorical variables?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/47638/55122)
and the much more general question
[In supervised learning, why is it bad to have correlated features?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/24452/55122)