# Which redundant feature should be use

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, correlation

I have two redundant features. A & B with 0.85 correlation. I know only one of them should be used to trained my model, but which feature should i use? A or B? Is there any method that can i use to know which redundant feature should i choosed? Or just select one of them randomly?

Comment: "only one of them should be used" isn't necessarily true, see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/24452/55122 for a start.  I've seen people choose the "better" feature to keep, but I'm not sure if there's much study into the bias-variance tradeoff inherent in making that decision in preprocessing (or leakage, if the decision is based in part on the test set).

Comment: Ben already touched on it with the linked thread; what kind of algorithms are you using? If it's a tree-based algorithm, feature removal in order to avoid colinear features isn't necessary in the first place.